# How to remove the additional(extra) backslashes present in HTML anchor tags?

Tags: php, html, string, backslash, stripslashes

I've following HTML string present in a variable titled `$text`:

```
$text = <a title=\"\" href=\"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/TXSta27QzqDnLeBXrZvX\"><img src=\"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/TXSta27QzqDnLeBXrZvX\" height=\"150px\" width=\"150px\"></a>

<a href=\"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/TXSta27QzqDnLeBXrZvX\" class=\"comment_attach_image_link_dwl\">Download</a>;
```

I want to remove those extra backslashes present in the HTML string. I f you observe closely these backslashes are present within the attributes as well like in **title, src, height, width, etc.** I want to remove all of them and want a final cleaned up HTML string.

It's not always that these extra backslashes are present in a HTML string. Sometimes it present, sometimes it's not. So the check for presence of these additional backslashes should also be performed. Only upon their presence the clean up operation should be carried out.

How should I do it in an reliable and efficient way?

Thanks.

Comment: The first line isn't valid PHP, you need quotes around the whole string.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `$text = "<a title=\"\"`? The backslashes are needed to prevent the quotes from ending the string. But they're not actually in the value of the string, they're just part of the literal syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try the following function:

```
<?php
echo stripslashes("Who\'s Peter Griffin?");
?>
```

Output:

Who's Peter Griffin?

Answer (score 1):

[str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

```
$text = '<a title=\"\" href=\"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/TXSta27QzqDnLeBXrZvX\"><img src=\"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/TXSta27QzqDnLeBXrZvX\" height=\"150px\" width=\"150px\"></a>';
$text = str_replace("\", "", $text);
```

This will remove all the backslashes in the string